# Eloquent eager load constrain by parent column values not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this following tables;

```
shipment
==========
date document_no address_id
----------------------------
2018-11-20 SO-18-11971 0
2018-11-20 SO-18-11971 1
2018-11-21 SO-18-11972 0


item
=======
shipment_date document_no address_id
-------------------------------------
2018-11-20 SO-18-11971 0
2018-11-20 SO-18-11971 1
2018-11-21 SO-18-11972 0
```

and below is the Models;

```
class Shipment extends Model {

    protected $table = 'shipment';

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'document_no', 'document_no')
            ->where(['shipment_date' => $this->date, 'address_id' => $this->address_id]);
    }
}

class Item extends Model {

    protected $table = 'item';
}
```

I tried to get the data for API;

```
return Shipment::with('items')->where('date', $shipment_date)->get()->toArray();
```

but I am getting empty `items`. But weirdly I am getting the `items` data when I am using this; `Shipment::find($id)->items`. What did I miss?

Comment: It's not possible to use `$this` in a relationship in combination with eager loading.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Any workaround? I am trying to display the `items`, but I don't want to update the table structure because it's already correct to me.

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thanks, please post this as answer, i'll mark it as correct answer. Although unfortunately this only solved half of my problem because of my use case is more complicated, but i'll create a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use `$this` in a relationship in combination with eager loading.

Take a look at this package: https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships

Answer (score 0):

that relation wont work correctly cause the structure is incorrect. try it like this

```
shipments
==========
id date document_no address_id
----------------------------
1 2018-11-20 SO-18-11971 0
2 2018-11-20 SO-18-11971 1
3 2018-11-21 SO-18-11972 0


item
=======
shipment_id
-------------------------------------
1
2
3
```

Less redundancy and more efficient. the relation will be

```
class Shipment extends Model {

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

take in count in my example i changed the table name from `shipment` to `shipments` so you dont need to declare the table or the foreign key.

that said, Eloquent (and Laravel) doesn't support multi key index in relations.